# How do I make an alert system using python

Tags: python, sockets, security, notifications, alert

Hi I want to make a simple alert system which will send an alert back to the server when a client is noticed by the software when accessing a specific website. For example if a user accesses eBay or yahoo then I should get an alert. is there anyway to do so ? I could really use help please.

thank you

Comment: Try combining these two things. `Python-iptables` to detect access. `Win10Toast` to give notifications on desktop. Or you could use another Python package to notify yourself via email. Google their names for documentation.

Comment: Here is how it should work :

1. be installed on user system
2. if user visits a site which matches the server's bad site list then alert the server

Comment: the server is on my end and the client app is on the user end...if the user visits a website which matches a list of harmful websites then the client app should alert the server!